# Change tintcolor of SFSafariViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

As the title says; how does one change the overall tint color of the new, in iOS 9, SFSafariViewController?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Some news from iOS 10: now we have two properties to control the overall looks of the `SFSafariViewController`

[image: doc]

*source: [link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller)*

The only downside is, of course, it's not available for older versions.

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    safariVC.preferredBarTintColor = .black
    safariVC.preferredControlTintColor = .white
} else {
    safariVC.view.tintColor = .someColor
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not affect the title / address :-(

Answer (score 22):

It's a property of the view, `safariVC.view.tintColor = UIColor.someColor()`

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for that.

Just use [CSafariWebKit](https://github.com/dmandarino/CSafariWebKit) and set the Color you want in BarTintColor and the TintColor:

So, you won't need to check if it's available. The frameworks does it for you

```
let vc = SafariViewController(url: url, barTintColor: nil, tintColor: nil)
vc.presentSafari(fromViewController: self, whenDidFinish: nil)
```