# SFSafariViewController title color change

Tags: ios, sfsafariviewcontroller

I'm using SFSafariViewController for show website in iphone i want to change color scheme like my app, i want to change color of  SFSafariViewController title at top.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change tintcolor of SFSafariViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913683/change-tintcolor-of-sfsafariviewcontroller)

Comment: Check it https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller/2274393-preferredcontroltintcolor

Comment: @ktr *preferredBarTintColor
The color to tint the background of the navigation bar and the toolbar.

Comment: @ktrkathir 
*preferredControlTintColor
The color to tint the control buttons on the navigation bar and the toolbar.

Comment: Not mention title color

Answer (score 1):

```
import SafariServices

extension UIViewController {

    /// Safari Service ViewController with
    /// - parameter link: initial load url
    func openSafariService(withURL link: String) {

        //  let url = link.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)

        if link.isNotBlank {
            let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: link)!, entersReaderIfAvailable: true)
            safariVC.preferredBarTintColor = UIColor.themeBlue
            safariVC.preferredControlTintColor = UIColor.white
            self.present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
}

// Update navigation bar
func updateNavigationBar() {
     navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.themeBlue
     navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
     navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
                                                                       NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.customFont(size: 17.0)]
}
```

I was updated my navigation bar then i call my safariService function its working fine for me.

[image]

Comment: It does not work

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change the URL "Title" color for SFSafariViewController. Its a default view of your web page. If you want the customisation you can use [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.green
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red
let attrs = [
      NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red
]
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attrs
```

Source : https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_sdk_chat_ios/issues/130